# What kinda error am I getting? Android Timer Error

Tags: android, timer

I don't understand why I am getting this Error.
I have been looking around at different codes and I used this Timer one because I don't know how to use Java Timers quite frankly and now it just crashes my app.. Any help please?

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.loadingn).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            findViewById(R.id.tuser).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tpass).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loginbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.username).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.pass).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }, 5000, 5000);
```

I forgot... Here is the Error(s) code:

```
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4176)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:749)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:805)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4005)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8591)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:6718)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:4632)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at info.david.statusbar.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:43)
12-24 05:53:19.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9887):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: you cannot access UI elements directly from a timer thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for Accessing Ui elements from `TimerTask` as :

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
   public void run() {
     Your_Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
         {
           public void run() 
            {

                   // access UI here
            }

      });
    }
 }, 5000, 5000);
```

Comment: And what will I do about the timer though? What do I do with that? or do I just put the code you stated in the TimerTask code

Comment: Thank you very very much Prosper K. Much appreciated! (: